# Are all linear maps from $\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}^n$ injective?

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $T:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}^n$ be a linear transformation. Is $T$ injective? I understand that if $T$ maps to a codomain of lower dimension then it is not necessarily linear, but if both the domain and codomain span $\mathbb{R}^n$, is $T$ injective? My understanding is yes, since for any $u,v\in\mathbb{R}^n$ we have
$$\begin{multline*}T(u)=T(v) \Longleftrightarrow T({u})-T({v})=0
                \Longleftrightarrow T({u})+T(-{v})=0 \\
                \Longleftrightarrow T({u}+(-{v}))=0 \Longleftrightarrow T({u}-{v})=0 \Longleftrightarrow {u}-{v}=0 \Longleftrightarrow {u}={v}\end{multline*}$$
Is there a counterexample? If so, what is the flaw in the proof?

Comment: $T(v)=0$ for all $v\in\mathbb R^n$ is linear as you can check.

Comment: $T(u-v)=0$ does not, in general, imply $u-v=0$.

Comment: If you add as an assumption the statement you seem to have been heading for, that the image of $T$ spans $\mathbb R^n,$ then yes $T$ will be injective.

Comment: If $T$ is surjective then yes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$T({u}-{v})=0 \Longleftrightarrow {u}-{v}=0$$

is not correct.

Put more simply, only one direction of $$T(w)=0 \Longleftrightarrow w=0$$ is correct. The forward implication is incorrect, as is shown by choosing any $T$ with a non-trivial kernel.

Answer (score 2):

What you have shown is that injectivity of $T$ is equivalent to $T$ having a trivial kernel. Of course, not all linear maps $\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^n$ have a trivial kernel (or equivalently, are injective), e.g., the zero map has the entire domain $\mathbb{R}^n$ as its kernel and is clearly not injective.